# I cannot access WD MyBookWorld World Edition from other network?

Tags: networking, external-hard-drive, network-shares, shared-folders

I configured WD MyBookWorld and join to the domain. Now it can be accessed in Local network. ex: 192.168.1.x

When I try to connect from another network(ex: 192.168.2.x). It cannot connect. But it can ping from another network. also, I can access the web from another network.

Answer (score 0):

`192.168.1.x`, and `192.168.2.x` are not necessarily on the same network, as you presume. If your `192.168.1.x` network has a `netmask` of `255.255.255.0`. Only clients (hosts) from `192.168.1.1` through `192.168.1.254` will be able to communicate with each other.

Instead, without complicating the matter. I might suggest that the easiest way to achieve your goal. Would be to change the `netmask` on your network to `255.255.252.0` ( `/22` in [CIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) notation ).
In doing so. The following range of addresses will be able to communicate with each other: `192.168.0.1` through `192.168.3.254`. Which will allow both of the networks you are attempting to communicate with, to reach each other. It will also allow for additional hosts in a broader range.

Comment: so what about if i have another network 192.168.125.x, 192.168.110.x ?

Comment: You need to add that range to the networks you described above?

Comment: yes. I have 7 kind of ranges.

Comment: Then you'll want to use a netmask of `255.255.128.0` a `/17` in CIDR notaion. This will give you `0 - 127` on the third octet. It's the closest "classfull" range to what you want to achieve.

Comment: no still not working. if I change it to `255.255.252.0` I can ping. But, still, I cannot access. I I change it to `255.255.128.0`, I cannot ping also. Also I restart wd mybookworld each time when I change netmask

Comment: Ahh. Sure. I didn't know the depth of your knowledge in this area. Now that I know: you will need to apply the *same* netmask to *all* of your devices. This way, they will *all* share the **same** *gateway*. Sorry. :) HTH

Comment: IOW use `255.255.128.0` on *all* your hosts, and connected devices.